# Quickly temporarily disabling snapping in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, snapping, digitizing, qgis-3

In some other applications I use you can use one of the "shift" keys to disable snapping for a single operation.

Is there an equivalent for the new node tool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes using `s` will enable/disable snapping.

Comment: Thnaks Nathan :) This does not appear to work on my Mac! (which is why I asked) I guess it must be a bug.  I'll report it once I figure out how.